# Downcast Base класса на несколько "поколений" вперёд

Tags: c++, наследование, cast

Имеется класс **A**, от него наследуется класс **B**, от которого наследуется класс **C**.
Как произвести приведение типов из **A** в **C**?

Код, с которым провожу эксперименты:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

class A
{
public:
    string str;
    A(string _str)
    {
        str = _str;
    }
    virtual ~A(){}
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    virtual string unpack(string t) = 0;
    virtual ~B(){}
};

class BA : public B
{
public:
    string unpack(string t) override
    {
        string temp = "a";
        return temp + str + t;
    }
    virtual ~BA(){}
};

class BB : public B
{
public:
    string unpack(string t) override
    {
        string temp = "a";
        return temp + str + t;
    }
    virtual ~BB(){}
};

template <typename TypeC>
TypeC *convert(A *_msg)
{
    auto msg = dynamic_cast<TypeC*>(_msg);
    return msg;
}

int main()
{
    A* a = new A("TEST_A");
    auto ba = convert<BA>(a);
    cout << ba->unpack("TEST_BA") << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: В этом примере приведение невозможно, так как создается только один единственный экземпляр класса A. А `dynamic_cast` сам по себе является порочной практикой, но при этом результат преобразования следует проверять прежде чем разыменовывать указатель.

Comment: Не надо дважды копировать строку в конструкторе; стоит добавить `delete`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Конечно же, вы не можете привести **реальный** объект A к типу AB!

А вот `AB` через указатель на `A` - можете.

Только надо дописать конструкторы...

```
class A
{
public:
    string str;
    A(string _str)
    {
        str = _str;
    }
    virtual ~A(){}
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    B(string _str):A(_str){}
    virtual string unpack(string t) = 0;
    virtual ~B(){}
};

class BA : public B
{
public:
    BA(string _str):B(_str){}
    string unpack(string t) override
    {
        string temp = "a";
        return temp + str + t;
    }
    virtual ~BA(){}
};

class BB : public B
{
public:
    string unpack(string t) override
    {
        string temp = "a";
        return temp + str + t;
    }
    virtual ~BB(){}
};

template <typename TypeC>
TypeC *convert(A *_msg)
{
    auto msg = dynamic_cast<TypeC*>(_msg);
    return msg;
}

int main()
{
    A* a = new BA("TEST_A");
    auto ba = convert<BA>(a);
    cout << ba->unpack("TEST_BA") << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Вот оно, главное -

```
    A* a = new BA("TEST_A");
```

Т.е. указатель на `A` указывает *на самом деле* на объект `BA` - и вот такой указатель вы можете привести к указателю на `BA`.

А вот если вы создали объект `A` - то как вы себе представляете приведение его к наследнику? У него же просто нет нужной функции `unpack`...

Чтобы убедиться - вам надо было в своем коде проверить результат преобразования:

```
A* a = new A("TEST_A");
auto ba = convert<BA>(a);

cout << ba << endl;
```

И вы бы увидели, что преобразование не выполнено: `ba == nullptr`...

Comment: Я понимаю, что у класса нет той же unpack, и проверку на nullptr не написал, потому что не хотел нагружать тем, что мне не нужно, тестовый код, когда я и так знаю, где программа ломается.
Моя основная проблема сейчас в том, что изначально у меня есть объект класса A, в нём есть данные, которые классы BA и BB парсят в свои собственные, причём разные, переменные.
По всей видимости, придется придти к другой реализации вышеописанной логики в проекте.

Comment: Я не знаю ваш проект, так что мне трудно советовать. Но пока что выглядит это примерно так - дедушка, зная, что внучок пошел в политику и напаковал себе кучу денег, решает разбогатеть - поскольку фамилии одинаковы, притворяется внучком и пытается снять денежки себе... :)